# How to get activity of a DecorVIew? .getContext() on DecorView getting a DecorContext

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-7.0-nougat

On Android 7, getting context of a `DecorView` returns a `DecorContext` class and it's not an Activity. I used to get activity using `Activity a = (Activity)view.getContext()` but it's not working for DecorView on Android 7 anymore. Is there any efficient way to get activity from a DecorView?

I'm using reflection to get the window of DecorView, and then get the context of that window (which is an Acitivity) for now.

```
Field f = decorView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mWindow");
f.setAccessible(true);
Window w = (Window) f.get(decorView);
Activity a = (Activity) w.getContext();
```

Is there any way that uses standard API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Android 7 (Nougat) Android introduced the multi-window feature, enabling you to open 2 activities at once on the screen (whether it's your activities or 2 different ones). To do that they introduced a new class called `DecorContext` to be used by the `DecorView`. The `DecorContext` is (quote) "Context for decor views which can be seeded with pure **application context** and *not depend on the activity*, but still provide some of the facilities that Activity has, e.g. themes, activity-based resources, etc.". This means that the `DecorView` no longer knows to which `Activity` it's related to, only to which `Application`. Hence going forward from Nougat, one cannot get the `Activity` from the `DecorView` alone.

Not sure if it's still relevant to you, but you can do this:

```
Activity a = (Activity) decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getContext();
```